# How do I replace values in an R dataframe column with a corresponding value?

Tags: r

Ok, so I have a dataframe that I downloaded from Pew Research Center. One of the columns (called 'cregion') contains a series of numbers from 1-56, with each number corresponding to a geographic location in the U.S. Most of these locations are states, and the additional 6 are at the sub-state level. So, for example, the number '1' corresponds to 'Alabama', and '11' corresponds to the 'District Of Columbia'.

What I'd like to do is replace each of those numbers in the 'cregion' column with the ACTUAL name of the region it corresponds to. Unfortunately, there is no column in this data frame that I can use to swap the values, as the key for which number corresponds to which region exists completely separately (word document). I'm new to R and while I've been searching for a few hours for the best way to go about this, I can't seem to find a method that would work (or I just don't understand the explanation). Can anybody suggest a method to me?

Comment: R installlations includes a US states database and the `match` function should do this neatly. Post a small data example that would form the basis of tested code. Coding is the focus of Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a vector of the state names as strings called `statevec` whose ith element corresponds to cregion i, and your data frame is named `dat`, just do

```
dat <- data.frame(cregion = sample(1:50), stuff = runif(50))
head(dat)
#  cregion       stuff
#1      25 0.665843896
#2      11 0.144631131
#3      13 0.691616240
#4      28 0.507454243
#5       9 0.416535139
#6      30 0.004196311
statevec <- state.name
dat$cregion <- statevec[dat$cregion]
head(dat)
#     cregion       stuff
#1   Missouri 0.665843896
#2     Hawaii 0.144631131
#3   Illinois 0.691616240
#4     Nevada 0.507454243
#5    Florida 0.416535139
#6 New Jersey 0.004196311
```

Comment: This is just `dat$cregion <- statevec` is it not? Ideally one would use `match` or `merge` for this sort of operation.

Comment: Only if `cregion==1:56`. I was thinking it could be e.g. `c(1,3,7,2)` etcetera

Comment: So, I just looked at the key again and for some reason, the way the data was organized, they skipped numbers. For example, 'Arizona' should have been number 3, not umber 4. If that's the case, then the approach you suggested won't work as straightforwardly as I would have liked. 

1 Alabama
2 Alaska
4 Arizona
5 Arkansas
6 California
8 Colorado
9 Connecticut
10 Delaware
11 District of Columbia
12 Florida
13 Georgia
15 Hawaii
16 Idaho

Comment: Ok, so I gave it a shot and your method does work as far as the ith element being able to replace the numbers with the corresponding states. Is there some way to define each element of the vector as being the "ith" element? For example, if Arizona is technically the 3rd element, but it actually corresponds to number 4, can I specify that in my 'statevec'?

Comment: Ok, I figured it out! I created the vector like you said, but for positions that were missing (#3 for example), I just wrote a "none" string, and wrote in 'Arizona' for #4. Thank you!